# Difference between using Chrome browser normally and via Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a website in Selenium WebDriver. The strange thing I'm coming across is when I open the website normally by starting Chrome, everything works as usual, but when I open it via Selenium Webdriver, the website produces a different response unlike the previous case.

I'm just curious what properties could differ here in both cases? Is there any way to copy/import the current Settings/Properties of Chrome in Selenium?

Comment: You can set ChromeOptions and certain DesiredCapabilities before instantiating the browser but I don’t think you can dynamically copy the settings from your own browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the same profile that you are using when launching manually then you can follow the below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chrome driver path goes here");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
# make sure don't specify '/Default' at the end of the user directory path below.
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: After trying this, I'm getting error `unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`

Comment: Here is the chomedriver documenation link http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities.